# Message: 'Undefined offset' - multiple file(image) upload

Tags: php, sql, database, model-view-controller, file-upload

Could someone please assist, as I am trying to upload multiple files(images) to the server as well as the file(image) names to different columns in the same database table.

The images uploads correctly to the server / folder, but I am currently unable to upload the file(image) names to the database when I select less than three files.

When I try to upload one file, I receive the error:
Message: 'Undefined offset: 1'

and when I try to upload two files: Message: 'Undefined offset: 2'.

Both errors refers the the line:

`$posts = Post::save($_FILES['file']['name'][0], $_FILES['file']['name'][1], $_FILES['file']['name'][2]);`

Please see the code in the Controller below:

```
public function createAction()
{              
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        // Sanitize POST array
        $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    
        // Count total files
        $countfiles = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
     
        // Looping all files
        for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){
            $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
    
            // Upload file
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], dirname(__DIR__)."/img/".$filename);
     
    }
 
    $posts = Post::save($_FILES['file']['name'][0], $_FILES['file']['name'][1], $_FILES['file']['name'][2]);    
         
    View::renderTemplate('posts/listinguploaded.html', []);
    }
}
```

Save method:

```
public static function save($file, $img2, $img3)
   
    {
 
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO posts (file, img2, img3)
                    VALUES (:file, :img2, :img3)';

            $db = static::getDB();
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bindValue(':file', $file, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(':img2', $img2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(':img3', $img3, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            
            return $stmt->execute();
        }
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Please always show us ALL of the error message not a summary

Comment: In this line `$posts = Post::save($_FILES['file']['name'][0], $_FILES['file']['name'][1], $_FILES['file']['name'][2]);` you always assume you have 3 files??? Earlier in the code you count how many are actaully being sent `$countfiles = count($_FILES['file']['name']);` so you will have use that count to make sure files are actually there and only use valid occurances

Comment: Agreed with @RiggsFolly . Do you always assume 3 files? What if user select only 2 files, the third index $_FILES['file']['name'][2] will obviously undefined.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you for the reply. Yes, that makes sense. Could you perhaps please inform me on how I could amend the code in order to make sure that files are there and then only use those occurrences?

Comment: Well there are a few things to think about here. First the prototype of the `Post::save()` method, First that need changing to allow for 1 or more parameters

Comment: Oh alright, thank you. Could you perhaps please advise on how I could do that?

Comment: Ok, if you want me to write it, show the code for the `save` method

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I have added the code for the save method in the original post.